# Как получить переменные из input?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Задача на python
Младший брат Аллы Вася делает тест по математике: вычисляет значение функций в различных точках. Стоит отличная погода, и друзья зовут Васю гулять. Но мама разрешила мальчику пойти на улицу только после того, как он закончит тест. К сожалению, Вася пока не умеет программировать. Зато Алла умеет. Она решила помочь брату и написала код функции y = ax2 + bx + c. Повторите успех Аллы. Напишите программу, которая будет по коэффициентам a, b, c и числу x выводить значение функции в точке x.

Формат ввода
На вход через пробел подаются числа a, x, b, c.

Формат вывода
Выведите одно число - значение функции в точке x.

Мой код:

```
function = (input('a, x, b, c'))
y = (a * (x**2)) + (b * x) + c
print (y)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Добавил свой код.

Comment: Но... вы ведь можете прочитать, как работает input и посмотреть примеры использования.

Comment: Посмотрел, можно так: a = list(map(int, input().split()))
Но как это применить не понимаю.

Comment: `a, b, c, x = map(int, input('a b c x').split())` и без списка можно...

Comment: a b c x-429
Вот такой ответ получается, а должно быть целое число)

Comment: вы через пробел вводите четыре числа и print (y) выводит "a b c x-429" строкой? не верю...

Comment: Сделал так:
a, x, b, c = map(int, input('a x b c').split())
y = (a * (x**2)) + (b * x) + c
print (y)
Ответ правильный, только переменный с переди лишние(

Comment: @Jack_oS я Вам честно говорю!

Comment: Зачем вам нужна подсказка input? Там же нет человека, который ее читает. Просто `input()`

Comment: @MBo Да, дело было именно в этом! Всем большое спасибо! Дело в том что это мой первый алгоритм, не судите строго! Всё работает)

Answer (score 1):

```
a, x, b, c = map(float, input().split())
y = a*x**2 + b*x + c
print(y)
```

Comment: На вход **через пробел** подаются числа a, x, b, c

Comment: внес правки, спасибо

Comment: В таком виде ответ не решает все проблемы автора